# Impact strength test of a container filled with liquid

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

as a university project I have to project(choose material and dimensioning) a liquid container (`NaClO`, density `1100 g/L`), we have choosen a `cylindric` shape (to avoid to calculate the stress on the handle).
However I have some difficulties to find a way to calculate the Impact strength stress of a liquid inside a container to define the thickness of the bottle, my question is: is there any ready to use formula? Is there any good approximation that can handle this event?

**EDIT**
What I thought: calculate the enrgy of the fall from 2-3m, set a reasonable strain and calculate the stress, then compare the breaking stress/yield stress (as Area the connection section from the base to the wall of the cylinder) with the one of the materials(we have restricted the field of selection to 6-9 material based on chemical properties)? is it a good way?

**EDIT 2**
Simplifying: is it fine (since the height is low and the volume of the liquid is 3-4L) to consider the liquid as a grave that falls from 2-3m on a section of the container or the laws that explain the falling of a luiquid inside a container are completely differents?

Comment: A formula won't help you if the manufacturer does not guarantee that his packaging product is tested against whatever impact scenario you have in mind. If you can't find manufacturer data, the easiest way is to test it yourself. Fill the container with water and do a worst case drop test (I would suggest 2-3m on a concrete floor). If it survives, you should be OK. That's how they do these things in real life, too. The containers they move nuclear waste in aren't just calculated, they are actually drop tested, and not just once.

Comment: A professor who tells you that you can't do an obvious experiment is a fool who should resign from his teaching position immediately. Tell him I said hello.

Comment: @CuriousOne Well,my bad I haven't been clear. We can't do it since the aim of the project is to choose the material based on calculos, so we use solid mechanics formulas to find out the thickness to avoid the breaking of the container, obviously in a industrial environment we have other way to try it out, but now we have just to define the hypothetical dimensions to make a potential prototype(that we will not do) and then do the real tests.

Comment: Oh my, so all you really want is for us to do your homework for you? OK... I vote to close, since you haven't shown us what you did to solve the problem.

Comment: @CuriousOne I have wrote it in one of my previous comment, however I have just edited the main question, however I'm not asking for a solution, I'm looking for a way/an approximation to be able to retrieve a "good" value...

Comment: I can't know what you have written in a previous question. What did you do since then? Please show your work.

Comment: @CuriousOne I have added another edit to the question, I haven't done any calculus since I'm not sure about I should proceed and I can't justify any result since I'm not sure about correctness of the concept, however if you need them I can output something

Comment: We are not your professor and we are not going to give you bad grades if your suggested solution is faulty. I do feel, though, that you won't learn much by not showing us at least a glimpse of what you have done. Honestly, I think you have done squat, and I really don't care about helping you. Find someone else.